# Worksheet_Change executed multiple times

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a MsgBox in an if else condition. When I use other conditions along with MsgBox, the MsgBox pops up multiple times and I have to end the program.

Code in a module:

```vb
Sub CheckValue(Target)
    If Target.Offset(0, 12) < 1 Then
        MsgBox "This is a sample box"
        Range(Target.Offset(0, -12), Cells(Target.MergeArea(1, 1).Row, Target.MergeArea(1, 1).Offset(1, -2).Column)).ClearContents
        Target.Offset(0, 0).ClearContents
        Target.Offset(-4, 0).Select
    End If
```

I activate this sub through worksheet change:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$N$16" Then
        Call CheckValue(Target)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you clear contents in your `CheckValue` sub, you are triggering the change-event.

You have to add  `Application.EnableEvents`

```vb
Sub CheckValue(Target)
If Target.Offset(0, 12) < 1 Then
     MsgBox "This is a sample box"

     Application.EnableEvents = false  '--> disable event
         Range(Target.Offset(0, -12), Cells(Target.MergeArea(1, 1).Row, Target.MergeArea(1, 1).Offset(1, -2).Column)).ClearContents
         Target.Offset(0, 0).ClearContents
     Application.EnableEvents = true    '--> enable events
     
     Target.Offset(-4, 0).Select

     End If
end sub
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked perfectly. But Does that means I use the Applciation.EnableEvents everytime ?

Comment: Yes - if you are changing cell $N$16 by code in other places as well you should add it.